# Two masses and two pulleys system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

Masses M1 and M2 are connected to a system of strings and pulleys as shown on the image bellow. The strings are massless and the pulleys massless and frictionless. I need to find the acceleration of M1.

I have found the following equations :

- M1a1 = M1g - T1
- M2a2 = M2g - T2
- a2 = 2a1
- 2T2 = T1

Putting everything together I found that the acceleration of M1 is g/3 if M1 = M2. But the right answer is g/5. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Image of the system]

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Do you delete answers pointing out sign errors when people post a homework question about tensor manipulation?